# How to validate, that there is at least one checkbox checked?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a form for creating a question with multiple(as many as one wishes) possible answers. Here is the picture:

[image]

The code for a single possible answer:

```html
<div class="input-group">

    {{-- Checkbox for the answer --}}
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[0][is_correct]" value="1">
    </span>

    {{-- Input field for the answer --}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[0][body]">

    {{-- . . . --}}

</div>
```

I need to validate that, there **exist at least three** answers for a question and **at least one of them is correct**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add html code for that form and your controller code (what have you tried so far)?

Comment: Clarification Request: I think you are programming a questionnaire, whereby the user is creating both the questions and the answers? The user needs to provide 3 possible answers, and specify which answer is correct by selecting one or more of the checkboxes? Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gravy Yes, exactly

Comment: @KuKeC I've updated the question.

Comment: are you looking to validate from server side?

Comment: @astroanu yes, naturally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider separating your answer text fields from your answer checkboxes for the sake of clarity.

Below hasn't been tested - but something like the following should hopefully help you along?

```
$numAnswers = count($input->only('answers_text'));
$rules = [
    'answers_checked' => 'array|min:1|max:' . $numAnswers,
    'answers_text' => 'array|min:3|required',
    'answers_text.*' => 'required|string',
];

$v = Validator::make($input, $rules);    
if ($v->fails()) {
  return response()->json($v->errors(), 422);
}
...
```

Comment: As I understand, you are suggesting that I change `answer[$var]['is_correct']` to `answers_checked[]`, but then, how will I be able to group the 'is_checked' and 'body' values together?

Comment: You could set them to have the same array index? `answers_text[0]` would relate to `answers_check[0]` and `answers_text[9]` would relate to `answers_check[9]` etc...

Comment: I see, thanks. One more question, though wouldn't `'answers_text' => 'array|min:3|required'` only check if there are 3 entries in the array, and ignore whether they are empty or not?

Comment: I have added another validation rule to help you to my answer 
`'answers_text.*' => 'required|string',` You can add `min:10` to enforce a min char length of 10 as an example. Please play around - and take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I've looked into the docs multiple times, but not really knowing what I was looking for, I have overseen this feature..