# Validation input checkbox at least one with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

does anyone know how to make validation checkbox to validate if the checkbox is checked at least one?

My Store method

```
public function store(CounselingRequest $request)
{
    $counseling = new Counseling();
    $counseling->student_id = $request->student_id;
    $counseling->user_id = Auth::user()->id;    
    $counseling->save(); 

    if ($request->has('problem_id')) { 
        $counseling->problems()->attach($request->problem_id);
    }

    return redirect('admin/counseling')->with('success', 'Data berhasil ditambah');
}
```

My Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'student_id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Something like that? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-without-all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate, that there is at least one checkbox checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599293/how-to-validate-that-there-is-at-least-one-checkbox-checked)